# How do I rerequest Facebook permissions in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

According to this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2#re-asking-declined-permissions

I add `auth_type: 'rerequest'` to the login call, but there is no option for that under `Accounts.loginWith<ExternalService>`. Is there a way to do it with `accounts-facebook` or any other package?

Comment: @abernix mentions such an option [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7078)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Accounts.loginWithFacebook({ auth_type: 'rerequest' })`